# c# MS Excel Application.ActiveSheet, can i save it in separate file?

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I develop "Excel 2007 add-in" and use "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application.ActiveSheet". How can I save it in separate file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found post explaining how to save active sheet in VB.NET:

```
Sub test()
  ActiveSheet.Copy
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\MyFolder\MySubFolder\Test.xls"
  ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

But you can try this logic in C#, switching active sheets and saving each separately

This should save them in seperate workbooks...

```
Sub test()

Dim iNoSheets As Integer
Dim i As Integer

iNoSheets = Worksheets.Count

For i = 1 To iNoSheets
Worksheets(i).Activate
ActiveSheet.Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Test" & i & ".xls"
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Next

End Sub
```

And now in C#:

```
public void SaveSheets()
{
for(int i = 0; i < Worksheets.Count; i++)
{
Worksheets[i].Activate();
ActiveSheet.Copy();
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(string.Format(@"C:\sheet{0}.xlsx",i));
ActiveWorkbook.Close();
}
}
```

Comment: Have you defined ActiveSheet in your class? And Worksheets? And ActiveWorkbook? Anyway this will save n copies of the whole workbook...

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign your active sheet to an `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet` object, and then just call the SaveAs method of this object like so:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Excel.Application ap = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook wb = ap.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\whatever.xlsx");
            Excel.Worksheet ws = wb.ActiveSheet;

            ws.SaveAs(@"C:\somethingelse.xlsx");

            ap.Workbooks.Close();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ap);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following working C# code is ready for copy & paste and will save the currently active Excel workbook (and write its name to the console if you uncomment the appropriate lines of code) under the given path:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Excel.Application objApp;

            objApp = (Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
            /*Console.WriteLine(objApp.ActiveWorkbook.Name);
            Console.ReadKey(); */

            objApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(@"C:\temp\ExcelTest\Test.xlsx", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault);
        }
    }
}
```